# Certificate authentication in React Native

Tags: react-native, authentication, axios, certificate, client-certificates

I am looking for a way in React native to authenticate each of my request using certificate credentials in Axios library.
In Native iOS, we do that using below way using the Alamofire library

```
let dataRequest = formDataRequest()
dataRequest.authenticate(with: urlCredential)
```

this urlCredential holds the certificate details such as list of certificates [SecCertificate], certificate identity - SecIdentity and persistence details.

Though I could not find a way to achieve the same in Reactnative using axios even after a lot of searching, through some hints, tried using the httpsAgent to append the certificate data as follows,

```
let axiosInstance = axios.create(config)
const certData = Buffer.from(certificateString, 'base64');
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
   config.httpsAgent = certData;
    return config;
});
```

Being said that above has not worked out, would like to understand,

1. Are interceptors / httpsAgent the right ways to append the certificate data ?
2. If yes, what would be the format that it would accept the certificates ?
3. If not, what is the proper way to achieve above type of authentication ?
4. If not, can we actually do such authentication using axios library or is there a preferred one ?